# docker-compose - Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

Trying to make docker container for my project and after using `docker-compose up --build` command I get this error: `Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html`.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

    RUN docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo_mysql \
        && a2enmod \
        rewrite
```

.env file

```
#PATHS

DB_PATH_HOST=./databases

APP_PATH_HOST=./wedding-planner

APP_PATH_CONTAINER=/var/www/html
```

part of docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'

    services:

        web:
            build: ./web
            environment:
                - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
[...]
        composer:
            image: composer:1.6
            volumes:
                - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
            working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
            command: composer install
```

Where should I put composer.json to make it work?

Comment: your composer image executes the composer install and looking for composer.json. In which way (dockerfile) did you get your composer.json onto the composer container?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your docker-compose.yml file is replacing the variables properly.

You can try something like this to export the variables for replacement:

```
set -a
. .env
set +a
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Comment: When I try to use `set -a` command it gives me an error: `Set-Variable : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'a'.`. Or should I do something else with these commands?